# Gibbs sampling proposals for bivariate normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I'm very familiar with Metropolis-Hastings, having implemented the algorithm myself to handle "toy problems." Gibbs sampling, however, is a bit trickier for me as I'm not quite certain what is/isn't required. I gather it flows as follows:

```
for i in iterations:
x_i+1 = P(x|y = y_i)
y_i+1 = P(y|x = x_i+1)
```

After some number of "burn in" iterations, the sampler will converge on the true target distribution. This is all well and good but I'm unclear on a few points:

1. Are these conditional distributions derived manually?
2. If so, how are points proposed? (I understand the acceptance to always be 100% in Gibbs)
3. Some problems, like image denoising, use actual tabular data; is data typically provided to a Gibbs sampler?

To make things more concrete, I'd like help sampling from a fictitious example. Say I want to sample from the bivariate normal distribution `N(mean=[0,1],cov=[[1,0.75],[0.75,0.5]])`.
Is the conditional distribution simply derived via Bayes rule?

```
P(x|y) = P(x,y)/P(y)
       = N(mean=[0,1],cov=[[1,0.75],[0.75,0.5]]) / N(mean=0,sigma=1)

P(y|x) = P(x,y)/P(x)
       = N(mean=[0,1],cov=[[1,0.75],[0.75,0.5]]) / N(mean=1,sigma=0.5)
```

To me this seems a bit like circular logic. How can we sample from this conditional distribution if it references a joint distribution and the whole point is to get the joint distribution? Likewise, I'm not sure how points from these conditional distributions are proposed. I understand that "Metropolis within Gibbs" exists, but at this point I'm more interested in "vanilla Gibbs".

To answer this question, please help me organize a design to sample from the mentioned bivariate normal with an eye for the questions laid out above. Thank you!

Comment: 1) yes. have a look at https://bragqut.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/deriving-the-full-conditionals.pdf

Comment: 2) new points are added to the chain by just sampling the parameters from the full conditional distributions

Comment: @carlo, I see, thanks! (Low key Gibbs is a lot trickier than I thought. I'm finding HMC more intuitive...)

Comment: well, I can't see how can you find HMC more intuitive, but i get the point. Gibbs sampling was so popular until some years ago because it's robust and doesn't need tuning, but it does need some preparation, so nowadays no-U-turn HMC is much more in fashion.